# Trigger to cancel transaction

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g, transactions

I have to enforce a rule based on a relatively complex query involving four tables. If any of the tables updates/inserts/deletes, I need to run the same query to check if the operation should be denied (by throwing an exception).

I think there must be four separate triggers because it seems that CREATE TRIGGER only accepts a single "on" clause; but I don't want to repeat the query, rather keeping it in a separate stored procedure.

I wonder if there is a way for the verification query to be given a representation of the database state as it would be after the event firing the trigger; and have the query be able to cancel that transaction if needed, rolling back to the state before the trigger was fired. This isn't what "before/for each row" does, I think; because that uses `:new` and `:old` - if I were to use the new row, I would have to rewrite the query four times substituting new in place of each respective table.

---

Adapted answer:

Even if I try my best to be horrible and set autocommit to be on, the 'after statement' trigger does the right thing; i.e. no rows are selected at the bottom of this block.

```
create or replace trigger test_after_tr
  after insert or update or delete on footable
begin
  raise_application_error(-20000, 'violated');
end;
/

set autocommit on;
begin
  execute immediate 'set autocommit on';
  insert into footable(name) values('fail');
exception when others then null;
end;
/

select * from footable where name = 'fail';
```

Comment: Hi, If i understood correctly , you have complex constraint which need to check & maintained across 4 tables.  Is my understanding is correct  or you give me example to understand better.

Comment: That's more or less true (although it's not a check constraint - because check constraints wouldn't be adequate).

Comment: just some out box qustions: 1) why data's are stored in 4 tables , if all the 4 tables are 1 -1 relations , then it can be in singe table. 2) can you make view out of these 4 tables and have trigger over view

Comment: They aren't 1-1 relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the database state after the statement using an "after statement" trigger (i.e. leaving out the `for each row` clause).  However you do not have access to `old` and `new` in a statement-level trigger.  You can either check that no data in the 4 tables breaks your rules (probably slow), or you can use row-level triggers on each table to record the keys of the affected records in a PL/SQL collection that you can then use to perform more selective queries in the "after statement" trigger.

Comment: If I use "after statement", would that already be too late to roll back by throwing an exception?

Comment: @Reinderien - an after trigger fires after the statement, not after the transaction ends - you can still roll back in response to the exception.

Comment: @AlexPoole What if the top-level caller has not explicitly started a transaction (in which case, I think, it's a one-statement transaction?)

Comment: @AlexPoole ok. So assuming that there are no inappropriate exception-swallowing blocks, for a single DML statement, the default action will be to roll back?

Comment: OK. Then probably `after statement` won't work because, unlike `before`/`for each row`, there is no guarantee of change rollback.

Comment: If the trigger (any trigger) raises an exception then the statement is rolled back

Comment: But it rolls back just the statement (to implicit savepoint), not the transaction, right? If it isn't a 'one-statement transaction' then the caller still needs to decide what to do when it handles the exception. I'm not sure if that is an issue here.

Comment: It seems (per code I posted in the question) the user isn't even able to do the wrong thing; that is, even if they try to ignore the exception, the violating action is still rolled back.

Comment: That's right, the statement has failed; the user can't "unfail" it by ignoring the exception.